# I am trying to list all IDs for all products that sold more than 20 units

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sqlplus

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT 
  Product_T.PRODUCTID, 
  Product_T.PRODUCTLINEID, 
  Product_T.PRODUCTDESCRIPTION, 
  Product_T.PRODUCTFINISH, 
  Product_T.PRODUCTSTANDARDPRICE, 
  Product_T.PRODUCTIONHAND, 
  OrderLine_T.ORDERLINEID, 
  OrderLine_TORDERID, 
  OrderLine_TPRODUCTID, 
  OrderLine_T.ORDEREDQUANTITY 
FROM 
  Product_T,
  OrderLine_T
WHERE 
  Product_T.ProductID = OrderLine_T.ProductID
AND 
  SUM(OrderLine_T.ORDEREDQUANTITY) > 20;
```

I get this message:

```
ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here
```

Any ideas? any help is appreciated

Comment: You can't put aggregate functions in a `where` clause. Use the appropriate `group by` clause and follow it up with `having sum(orderline_t.orderedquantity) > 20`.

Comment: see this : http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00934.php

Answer (score 1):

Use HAVING instead

```
SELECT 
Product_T.PRODUCTID, 
Product_T.PRODUCTLINEID, 
Product_T.PRODUCTDESCRIPTION, 
Product_T.PRODUCTFINISH, 
Product_T.PRODUCTSTANDARDPRICE, 
Product_T.PRODUCTIONHAND, 
OrderLine_T.ORDERLINEID, 
OrderLine_TORDERID, 
OrderLine_TPRODUCTID, 
SUM(OrderLine_T.ORDEREDQUANTITY) OrderQty
FROM 
Product_T,
OrderLine_T
WHERE 
Product_T.ProductID = OrderLine_T.ProductID
GROUP BY
Product_T.PRODUCTID, 
Product_T.PRODUCTLINEID, 
Product_T.PRODUCTDESCRIPTION, 
Product_T.PRODUCTFINISH, 
Product_T.PRODUCTSTANDARDPRICE, 
Product_T.PRODUCTIONHAND, 
OrderLine_T.ORDERLINEID, 
OrderLine_TORDERID, 
OrderLine_TPRODUCTID
HAVING
SUM(OrderLine_T.ORDEREDQUANTITY) > 20;
```